# Regex to identify all wrong HTML special chars

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a huge HTML with several special chars, in the forms `&nbsp;` or `"&#82173333;`.

Some of them are wrong, because **they lack the initial &**.

I would like to **search for such wrong spacial chars**. I know that I can search all the right special chars by means of the following regex:

```
       \&(?:[a-z]+|#x?\d+);\
```

But I'd need a **regex useful to search the wrong ones** (without the initial &).
Can you help me? 
Thanks in advance

Edit:

As suggested, I'll post an example. My HTML cointains the following statement:

```
   <![CDATA[<nolink>blablabla&nbsp;blablabla</nolink>]]>quot;
```

where we have 2 special HTML character:

- `&nbsp;`
- `quot;`

I'm interested in finding the second item, because it is wrong (laking the initial &).

So the output of the requested regex should be: `quot;`

Comment: It's not *exactly* clear what you're after. Post samples of incorrect code and it's corrected output. Also, what if you have a sentence like `Some numbers are prime; but others are not` (note that `&prime;` is a valid HTML entity)? What makes `nbsp;` special?

Comment: So you have a certain rule you can apply? like do they all contain an apostrophe in the end? Because as far as I see it you have 3 relevant groups of Strings: html code, wrong special characters and correct special characters. And to my understanding, you cant separate these groups with a ruleset unique to them, to single them out. Meaning you need a common rule for the wrong special characters. Like "does not start with `&`but ends with `;`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm searching for the rule "does not start with & but ends with ;" which isolates only the **wrong** special characters among the aforementioned three relevant groups of Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build on

```
(?<!&)(?:\b(?:nbsp|quot|divide)|#[0-9a-f]+);
```

adding the "special chars" you need.

This simple one matches a sequence, not preceded by a `&` (the negative lookbehind `(?<!&)` makes sure of that), thats is either

- nbsp
- quot
- a hexadecimal number, prefixed with `#` (`#[0-9a-f]+`)

(Add case insensitive flag to make hex chars able to be upper case.)

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QZs5bM/8).

**Edit**
Added a check for *word break* (`\b`) before the "word entities" to make sure it doesn't match partial entities (if there are any).

**Edit 2**
To have a generic re matching all entities (and possibly other non-entity words) try

```
(?<!&)(?:\b(?:[a-z]{2,8}\d{0,2})|#[0-9a-f]+);
```

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QZs5bM/9).

Comment: thanks a lot! I easy modified your example inserting the *divide;* wrong special character. The regex is almost perfect, but it match also the **ivide;** (or also **bsp;**): [see the example](https://regex101.com/r/QZs5bM/6)

Comment: Updated regex and example.

Comment: The solution is fine but it isn't general enough: the problem is that I don't know what exactly special characters there are in the HTML. The regex works well but it forces me to specify all the possible cases. Here a list of all special chars: [HTML Codes Table](https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: So you want some *magic* understanding of the difference between  `Text with nbsp; here`, and `List of names; Arnold, Sylvester`?

Comment: Not at all: the number of occurrences of the type: `List of names;` is very low and I don't worry about it

Comment: But I admit that if there isn't some sort of initial escape character (i.e., white space) it necessary to specify each character code I'm interested in

Answer (score 0):

I tried: `\s(?!&)[A-Za-z0-9]+;`

Tried it at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) with

```
&wudhilweuh212313i9dioed;  wcihecrehc; &wkjdnwkne13131; eiou2ei; 1121i2093;
qeoidjwidw29i1291;
```

matching

```
wcihecrehc; eiou2ei; 1121i2093;
qeoidjwidw29i1291;
```

My examples are just randomness. Why? As far as I understood it you wanted anything that has a String consisting of `A-Z`, `a-z` and `0-9` that does start with a whitespace character, not followed by `&` and ending with `;`. So I didn't want to make it too restricted.

Comment: yes, unfortunately the statement "that does start with a whitespace character" is a too strong restriction because most of the special chars do not start with white space